Trouble purging varnish cache (Nginx+Varnish+SSL)
OK, I have setup a private server at home in the following configuration:
Nginx+Varnish+SSL (CacheServer) <->  Nginx+PhP (webserver)
There is a single public facing IPv4 address that is running through Cloudflare.
The public IP address resolves to the (CacheServer), there are no other avaliable IP's to point to and of course the two servers have private communication with each other via internal IP addresses
Everything is setup with virtual hosts so multiple websites run on this server setup.
I have been able to get most everything to work... except I cannot get varnish to purge through any means away from the server (wordpress site plugins, and methods that would happen any time a site/page is updated.)
Here is the purge section from my VCL:
    if(req.method == "PURGE") {
        if(!client.ip ~ purge) {
            return(synth(405,"PURGE not allowed for this IP address"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Purge-Method == "regex") {
            ban("obj.http.x-url ~ " + req.url + " && obj.http.x-host == " + req.http.host);
            return(synth(200, "Purged"));
        }
        ban("obj.http.x-url == " + req.url + " && obj.http.x-host == " + req.http.host);
        return(synth(200, "Purged"));
    }

I can post any other conf or vcl file content that would help fix this.
I have tried installing a variaty of cache purging wordpress plugins. I started with the guide found here: https://ciffonedigital.com/installing-wordpress-on-lemp-with-varnish-cache/
That is what guided 99% of the configurations, however this varnish cache purge setup does not seem to work. It says to configure it with the cacheserver's private IP address plus the port.
I also tried wprocket (since it plays nicely with cloudflare and varnish) with no luck, I added the specific helper plugin for being able to configure custom IP address with cloudflare proxy, configured as above (also tried leaving it unchanged with localhost)
I don't even know where to find where the error is. All I know is the age of the cached file only resets if I $ sudo systemctl restart varnish
Hopefully it's something I just didn't know i needed, like forwarding a port or setting some constant somewhere...
Thanks in advance!!

This is the official WordPress & Varnish tutorial we recommend: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/configuring-varnish-wordpress/.
Monitoring the error
Before we can start changing configurations, we need to know what the exact error is. We can use varnishlog for that.
To capture PURGE requests, we can filter the logs using the following varnishlog command:
sudo varnishlog -g request -q "ReqMethod eq 'PURGE'"

This will display all log transactions that use the PURGE request method. Please have a look at the log output and check whether there is useful information in there.
Don't hesitate to attach the log output to your question so I can help you out.
A likely issue
While I don't know what is causing your WordPress issue, I do see a likely root cause. I believe it's related to the Access Control List and how you validate it.
The if(!client.ip ~ purge) {} code in your VCL file will try to match the client IP address to an ACL called purge. If the client IP doesn't match, the synthetic error is returned.
But since Nginx is sitting in front of Varnish, it will always have the same IP address, which might not be part of the ACL. And we cannot add Nginx' IP address to the ACL, because it would open the flood gates for anyone to purge.
So instead of using client.ip to get the client IP address, we're going to use std.ip(req.http.X-forwarded-for, "0.0.0.0") as documented here: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vmod_std.html#std-ip.
This function will convert the value of the X-Forwarded-For header to an IP address and match it to the ACL. The X-Forwarded-For header value is set by Nginx because Nginx knows the IP address of the actual client, since it's in charge of terminating the TLS.

IMPORTANT: in order to use the std.ip() function, you need to import vmod_std in your VCL file. This is done by adding import std; near the top of your VCL file.

In the end your purging logic will look like this:
import std;

acl purge {
    //IP addresses, subnets & hostnames go here
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if(req.method == "PURGE") {
        if(!std.ip(req.http.X-Forwarded-For, "0.0.0.0") ~ purge) {
            return(synth(405,"PURGE not allowed for this IP address"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Purge-Method == "regex") {
            ban("obj.http.x-url ~ " + req.url + " && obj.http.x-host == " + req.http.host);
            return(synth(200, "Purged"));
        }
        ban("obj.http.x-url == " + req.url + " && obj.http.x-host == " + req.http.host);
        return(synth(200, "Purged"));
    }
}

Conclusion
While there's no guarantee that the std.ip() function will solve your problem, it sure looks like it could be the issue.
Just to be on the safe side, I recommend that you look at the logs using the sudo varnishlog -g request -q "ReqMethod eq 'PURGE'" command. The output will tell you why it is failing.

This is great! I'll dive into this tonight and let you know how it goes. Even if this doesn't solve my issue this is an amazing resource that will help tremendously.

Sadly I am still unable to get it to work.
First, the logging check never showed any results for PURGED, I was able to get some status by running the systemctl status varnish, however the failure wasn't much help to me nor to google.
May 10 07:07:27 cache-server varnishd[55018]: CLI telnet  54348  Rd PURGE /.* HTTP/1.1
May 10 07:07:27 cache-server varnishd[55018]: CLI telnet  54348  Wr 101 Unknown request.

Also, Something odd. When I run a  $ curl -x Ban  I get a fully formatted 405 response (HTML markup) that does not match the one added to the default.vcl. It must be getting it from somewhere but it isn't the VCL's that are loaded...

@Phil Check your WordPress configuration, because if the sudo varnishlog -g request -q "ReqMethod eq 'PURGE'" command doesn't show the purge requests, it means WordPress is sending them elsewhere.

@Phil Also, if you're running the curl -XPURGE command on the local server, the IP address and port might be different from when you're running it through Nginx. Make sure your WordPress config talks directly to Varnish on its port (which is defined by the varnishd parameter called -a.

So I wanted to drop by to say I figured this out. I'll write a more complete answer for the community after I finish rebuilding the sever (separate issue). For now, it was a combination of IP addresses and a cloudflare rule. that eventually fixed it. Now, we shall see if I can reproduce it after I am done redoing everything.
